# Django Rest Framework: How to pass a list of UUIDs for a nested relationship to a serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-serializer, django-tests

**TL;DR**: What could be the reason the incoming data for one of my serializers does not get processed?

I'm working on a serializer for a nested relationship. The serializer should get a list of UUIDs, so that I can make many to many relationships. Here is the model:

```
class Order(
    UniversallyUniqueIdentifiable,
    SoftDeletableModel,
    TimeStampedModel,
    models.Model
):
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    custom_choice_items = models.ManyToManyField(CustomChoiceItem, blank=True)
    price = models.ForeignKey(MenuItemPrice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(MINIMUM_ORDER_AMOUNT)]
    )
```

Here is the data (my post body) with which I hit the route in my tests:

```
data = {
    "checkin_uuid": self.checkin.uuid,
    "custom_choice_items": [],
    "menu_item": self.menu_item.uuid,
    "price": self.menu_item_price.uuid,
    "amount": ORDER_AMOUNT,
}
response = self.client.post(self.order_consumer_create_url, self.data)
```

Note that the empty list for `custom_choice_items` does not change anything. Even if I fill it with values the same error occurs. And last but not least here are the serializers:

```
class CustomChoiceItemUUIDSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer just for the uuids, which is used when creating orders."""
    class Meta:
        model = CustomChoiceItem
        fields = ["uuid"]
....
# The serializer that does not work
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    menu_item = serializers.UUIDField(source="menu_item.uuid")
    custom_choice_items = CustomChoiceItemUUIDSerializer()
    price = serializers.UUIDField(source="price.uuid")
    wish = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [
            "uuid",
            "menu_item",
            "custom_choice_items",
            "price",
            "amount",
            "wish",
        ]
```

The problem is now, that when I leave out `many=True`, I get the error:

```
{'custom_choice_items': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

And If I set `many=True` I just simply don't get any data. By that I mean e.g. the value of `validated_data["custom_choice_items"]` in the serializers `create()` method is just empty.

What goes wrong here?

I even checked that the data is in the request `self.context["request"].data` includes a key `custom_choice_items` the way I pass the data to this view!

EDIT: Here is the data I pass to custom_choice_items:

```
   data = {
       “checkin_uuid”: self.checkin.uuid,
       “custom_choice_items”: [{“uuid”: custom_choice_item.uuid}],
       “menu_item”: self.menu_item.uuid,
       “price”: self.menu_item_price.uuid,
       “amount”: ORDER_AMOUNT,
   }
   self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=“Token ” + self.token.key)
   response = self.client.post(self.order_consumer_create_url, data)
```

Comment: Does `uuid` primary key of `CustomChoiceItem` model? Can you share body of posted request?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner UUID is not the primary key of the `customchoiceitem`. The body of the post requst is what is in data (I edited the post) :)

Comment: I mean can you add what you pass with `custom_choice_items` also?:) Does `uuid` unique for CustomChoiceItem?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Sure I added it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post data using the test api client, if the data contains nested structure you should use `format=json`, like this:

```
response = self.client.post(self.order_consumer_create_url, data, format='json')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you override `.create` method in the serializer? Something like this should work:

```
from django.db import transaction

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # your fields and Meta class here

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        custom_choice_items = validated_data.pop('custom_choice_items')
        order = super().create(validated_data)

        order.custom_choice_items.add(*custom_choice_items)
        return order
```

By the way you don't really need to define `CustomChoiceItemUUIDSerializer` if is just the primary key of that.

Comment: No the uuid is not the primary key. That is exactly what I did. I did override `.create()`, but this line `custom_choice_items = validated_data.pop('custom_choice_items')` does not work. It is always none if I set `many=True` and it not having `many=True` throws an field required error.

Comment: You should add `many=True` for that custom serializer. If that can be an empty list then add this `allow_empty=True` to allow empty list to be sent, also you can put `required=False` if that field is not required (you don't send it at all).

Comment: I did add `many=True` but that only does not help. I still get no value no matter what happens.

Comment: can you try with this? `response = self.client.post(self.order_consumer_create_url, data, format='json')`

Comment: You literal god. I chewed on this problem for almost a day now, and the only thing wrong was the test case. Thank you very much! If you post this comment as an answer I will accept it.